# Is there an optimal timestamp format for querying bi-temporal data in MarkLogic?

Tags: xsd, marklogic, datetime-format, bi-temporal

I have two date formats for validStartDtTm (name of validAxes) stored in one collection. I want to harmonize all of the dates into one uniform format and wanted to know if there were any best practices for bi-temporal date format in MarkLogic.

Current formats are as follows:

1. **2019-04-09T10:54:37.861434Z** - generated by front end users and stored without transformation
2. **2019-04-09T10:54:37.8614534-04:00** - ingested from back end with format 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS' and transformed using xdmp.parseDateTime

Thanks!

Comment: Just write a few lines and analyze the different behaviors of the timestamp formats while reading, writing and saving. This is not a real problem and reminds me of a [horse race question](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

Comment: If you are using them in a dateTime index, then the value will need to be valid for that (both of these are valid).  Best idea is to reject invalid values for the index.  All dateTimes will be stored in UTC ('Z' offset) in the server so the input format/offset isn't retained after ingest.

Answer (score 2):

These are both [valid `xs:dateTime` values](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#dt-dt-7PropMod) so they don't need harmonization per se, but each indicates a different time zone, so you should check to be sure those are what is intended.

Both times are in the same format, The "Z" trailing the first time indicates "Zulu" time, i.e. UTC, the equivalent of `2019-04-09T10:54:37.861434-00:00`. The "-04:00` trailing the second time indicates the time is behind USC by 4 hours and 0 minutes.